# How to sort a DataView in a case-insensitive manner?

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable, dataview

I have a DataTable.  I'd like to sort its default view by a column name 'city'.  I'd like the sort to be case-insensitive.

Here is the code I have:

```
DataTable dt = GetDataFromSource();
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "city asc";

MyReport.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mind.  It's in the documentation.

```
DataTable dt = GetDataFromSource();
dt.CaseSensitive = false;
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "city asc";
```

Comment: Shouldn't `CaseSensitive` be `false` to be case-insensitive?